# Download spreadsheet to android studio app

Tags: android

Hi Can someone explain to me how what each line does in this code? 
(from http://blogs.telerik.com/androidteam/posts/15-01-21/google-spreadsheet-as-data-source-android)

I'm trying to download a google spreadsheet to my android app, but I'm having some difficulty in how. So I found this link, but I don't understand it!

Comment: "Can someone explain to me how what each line does in this code?" -- can you explain what **specifically** you do not understand?

Comment: Did you even try to implement the said code before declaring that you don't understand it?

Comment: I don't understand what this does                                                         public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  public DownloadWebpageTask(AsyncResult callback) {

        this.callback = callback;

    }

Comment: Does the method doInbackground in charge of downloading the URL?

Comment: And if someone can explain to me what the method onPostExcute does that would be great as well. (Is it to convert the downloaded spreadsheet into a Json object?)

Comment: Yes Razgriz I have implemented it, I get the gist of it, but I also need to write my own code, and I was hoping to learn from this code line by line first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions in the comments (kindly edit those in your question):

**Does the method doInbackground in charge of downloading the URL?**

Yes. The Android OS does NOT allow Network Processes (anything that has to do with downloading/uploading) on the Main Thread/UI Thread since processes like such tend to eat up a lot of resources and can make your application slow and laggy. To remedy this, Android recommends you do the Network Processes on an `AsyncTask` so that it will run the Network Processes on a background thread.

**And if someone can explain to me what the method onPostExcute does that would be great as well. (Is it to convert the downloaded spreadsheet into a Json object?)**

Normally, after you download what you need from your online resource (in your case, the spreadsheet) in the `doInBackground` method of the `AsyncTask`, you do what ever post download processing you need to do in the `onPostExecute`. For example, you want to parse the spreadsheet, you do it in that function. `onPostExecute` is for doing anything you want after you've downloaded the spreadsheet. Personally, I use this for showing an `AlertDialog` or a `Toast` to tell the user that the download has finished.

There are also examples of using a progress dialog to show the user how is download/upload is doing.

Note: A common mistake is to do something UI related in the `doInBackground` method. The Android OS will now allow such actions since the `doInBackground` is dedicated for doing non-UI related code.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much! It has definitely helped my understanding of the code!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I also had a hard time understanding AsyncTasks before. You can upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.